# Project Euler problem 1 in Factor

Tags: project-euler, factor-lang

I'm a complete beginner of [Factor](http://factorcode.org/), but I just managed to solved [Euler Problem #1](http://projecteuler.net/problem=1) using it, and would love to have the code reviewed. Anything that can be improved? In particular I'm wondering if there is a cleaner or more idiomatic way to write the **mult3or5?** word.

```
USING: math kernel sequences math.ranges prettyprint ;
IN: euler1

: mult? ( x y -- ? ) rem 0 = ;

: mult3? ( x -- ? ) 3 mult? ;
: mult5? ( x -- ? ) 5 mult? ;

: mult3or5? ( x -- ? ) dup mult3? swap mult5? or ;

: sumMultsOf3or5 ( seq -- n ) [ mult3or5? ] filter sum ;

: solveEuler1 ( -- ) 0 1000 (a,b) sumMultsOf3or5 . ;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

dup f swap g is a common idiom, so Factor has bi.

```
: mult3or5? ( x -- ? ) [ mult3? ] [ mult5? ] bi or ;
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm a Factor beginner too, but I'd use the `zero?` word from `math` in the definition of `mult`:

```
: mult? ( x y -- ? ) rem zero? ;
```

Comment: Thanks. A small improvement though. Let me know if you find something else.